# Persist Angular Service values when same component used multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am having issue with persisting values for an angular component when it is being used multiple times on the page.

I have a angular component which itself has its own service and makes an http call. Now i am going to use this component multiple times on the page, but i want to restrict the http call to happen only once.

For this i tried below code but this doesn't seems to work. Could someone throw some inputs here.

****Parent Component HTML****

```html
<component-parent>
  <child-comp [input1]="xyz" [input2] = "abc"></child-comp>
  <div> test content </div>
  <div> test content 2 </div>
  <child-comp [input1]="111" [input2] = "222"></child-comp> 
</component-parent>
```

****child component.ts****

```js
this.childCompService.getResults(this.input1, this.input2).subscribe((resp) =>{
  //some processing data
})
```

****child Component service.ts****

```js
private results = []<any>;
getResults(inp1, inp2):observable<any> {
  if (this.results && this.results.length > 0) {
    //do not make httpcall
    // process results and return
    of(this.results)
  } else {
    this.http.get(url, payload).subscribe((val) => {
      this.results = value
    })
  }
}
```

Is there a way using RXJS i can persist the http results fetched first time and do not make the call again.

Comment: Are you creating the service every time the component initialse?

Comment: yes, the http call is happening in the service associated with the child component and this component is added dynamically. So i can't move the http call to parent.

Comment: The question : does your service initialise every time you make a call?

Comment: yes it is getting initialised every time the component loads.

Comment: Do the `url` & `payload` passed to HTTP `get`, related to the child component?

Comment: The answer below is a reasonable solution, but my question is why you are having the children make the HTTP call? Why not instead have the parent make the call to the service and pass the result as an input?

Comment: You can use @Injectable to move service instance to a NgModule or Root injector. That way, even if you use child component at multiple places, the service gets initialised only once (depending on the injector), and you can cache the API result inside of the service. If cached data is present, return that, else make fresh HTTP call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is initialised every time you create a component, save the data in the local storage as a persistent layer. So, every time you make a call check if it exists else call the api :

```
getResults(inp1, inp2):observable<any>{

  const data = localStorage.getItem('results');
  if(data){
    //do not make httpcall
    // process results and return
    of(data)
  }else{
    this.http.get(url, payload).subscribe((val) => {
        this.results = val;
        localStorage.setItem('results', JSON.stringify(val))
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this. But i am seeing if there is any other way to achieve this. And another thing is if we persist in local storage we don’t know when to clear this value. Because when we go to next page I want the call to happen again.

Comment: You can use versioning key for this if possible. If your data from the API changes very often then it doesn't make sense to create a persistent layer, you can keep calling the API. You can use clear this local storage every time you change the page.

Comment: I used this solution but having one issue here. The initiation is happening even before i get the response from first one. So for every execution the localstorage value is empty and api call is happening twice still. Do you have any suggestions to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BehaviorSubject` here.

**child Component service.ts**

```js
export class ChildService {
    public static resultSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
    getResults(inp1, inp2):observable<any> {
      if(this.resultSubject$.getValue()){
        return ChildService.resultSubject$.asObservable();
      }
      return this.http.get(url, payload).pipe(
          tap(val => ChildService.resultSubject$.next(val)
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't work because the service re-inits every time the API is being called. First of all the service needs to be re-init only once then this solution would work.

Comment: Making the BehaviorSubject a static variable will work I guess. Try, Updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Your client component should persist the result as the result from the service should be stateless and cannot be shared by multiple instances of the client component unless you store this in a backend data store and retrieve it for each client component.

Each instance of the client component will have it's own copy of the result from the service, so you can then determine when the result from the service is non-null or a non-empty array.

if either of these conditions is met then allow the service to be called from your client component.

The suggestion below can be called after you have set both the inputs and the method callService() is called within an @Input() setter.

Client Component:

```
returnResult: any[] = [];
_input1: string = '';
_input2: string = '';

@Input('input1')
set input1(value: string)
{
    if (!value)
      return;
    this._input1 = value;
    if ((this._input1.length > 0) && (this._input2.length > 0))
       this.callService();
}

@Input('input2')
set input2(value: string)
{
    if (!value)
      return;
    this._input2 = value;
    if ((this._input1.length > 0) && (this._input2.length > 0))
       this.callService();
}

callService()
{
    if (!this.returnResult || this.returnResult.length === 0)
    {
        this.childCompService.getResults(this.input1, this.input2)
            .subscribe((resp) => {
                //some processing data
                this.returnResult = resp;
            });
    }
}
```

Service Component:

```
getResults(inp1, inp2):observable<any> {
    // setup payload with inp1 and inp2 ..

    return this.http.get(url, payload);
}
```